# How can I apply font-family from options list via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, font-family

I have compiled a list of font-families in an options list (drop-down) that can be seen below, how can I apply a font-family to text in a div via jQuery. Let me say that I have a div which holds text in it, and moreover I have an options drop-down list which has list of font families, now I want to select a font family name from the dropdown list and the text in the div should be applied with the selected font family from the list.

```
<div id="test_text">Test Text</div>

<select id="font_families">
                    
                        <option value="JasmineUPC">JasmineUPC</option>
                        <option value="Javanese Text">Javanese Text</option>
                        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                        <option value="Verdana">Verdana </option>
                        <option value="Impact">Impact </option>
                        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
                        
                        <option value="Geneva">Geneva</option>
                        <option value="Segoe UI">Segoe UI</option>
                        <option value="Optima">Optima</option>
                        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                        
                        <option value="Big Caslon">Big Caslon</option>
                        <option value="Bodoni MT">Bodoni MT</option>
                        <option value="Book Antiqua">Book Antiqua</option>
                        <option value="Bookman">Bookman</option>
                        
                        <option value="New Century Schoolbook">New Century Schoolbook</option>
                        <option value="Calisto MT">Calisto MT </option>
                        <option value="Cambria">Cambria</option>
                        <option value="Didot">Didot</option>
                        
                        <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
                        <option value="Georgia">Georgia </option>
                        <option value="Goudy Old Style">Goudy Old Style</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Bright">Lucida Bright</option>
                        
                        <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
                        <option value="Perpetua ">Perpetua </option>
                        <option value="Rockwell">Rockwell</option>
                        <option value="Rockwell Extra Bold">Rockwell Extra Bold</option>
                        
                        <option value="Consolas">Consolas</option>
                        <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
                        <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Console">Lucida Console</option>
                        
                        <option value="Lucidatypewriter">Lucidatypewriter</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Sans Typewriter">Lucida Sans Typewriter</option>
                        <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                        <option value="Andale Mono">Andale Mono</option>
                        
                        <option value="Apple Chancery">Apple Chancery</option>
                        <option value="Zapf Chancery">Zapf Chancery</option>
                        <option value="Bradley Hand">Bradley Hand</option>
                        <option value="Brush Script MT">Brush Script MT</option>
                        
                        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                        <option value="Verdana ">Verdana </option>
                        <option value="Impact ">Impact </option>
                        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
                        
                        <option value="Brush Script Std">Brush Script Std</option>
                        <option value="Snell Roundhan">Snell Roundhan</option>
                        <option value="URW Chancery">URW Chancery</option>
                        <option value="Coronet script">Coronet script</option>
                        
                        <option value="Florence">Florence</option>
                        <option value="Parkavenue">Parkavenue </option>
                        <option value="Brushstroke">Brushstroke</option>
                        <option value="Luminari">Luminari</option>
                        
                        <option value="Chalkduster">Chalkduster</option>
                        <option value="Jazz LET">Jazz LET </option>
                        <option value="Blippo">Blippo</option>
                        <option value="Stencil Std">Stencil Std</option>
                        
                        <option value="Marker Felt">Marker Felt</option>
                        <option value="Trattatello">Trattatello </option>
                        <option value="Arnoldboecklin">Arnoldboecklin</option>
                        <option value="Oldtown">Oldtown</option>
                        
                        <option value="Copperplate">Copperplate</option>
                        <option value="papyrus">papyrus </option>
                        <option value="Abadi MT Condensed Light">Abadi MT Condensed Light</option>
                        <option value="Aharoni">Aharoni</option>
                        
                        <option value="Aharoni Bold">Aharoni Bold</option>
                        <option value="Aldhabi">Aldhabi </option>
                        <option value="AlternateGothic2 BT">AlternateGothic2 BT</option>
                        <option value="Andale Mono">Andale Mono</option>
                        
                        <option value="Andalus">Andalus</option>
                        <option value="Angsana New">Angsana New </option>
                        <option value="AngsanaUPC">AngsanaUPC</option>
                        <option value="Aparajita">Aparajita</option>
                        
                        <option value="Apple Chancery">Apple Chancery</option>
                        <option value="Arabic Typesetting">Arabic Typesetting </option>
                        <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
                        <option value="Arial narrow">Arial narrow</option>
                        
                        <option value="Arial Nova">Arial Nova</option>
                        <option value="Arial Rounded MT Bold">Arial Rounded MT Bold </option>
                        <option value="Arnoldboecklin">Arnoldboecklin</option>
                        <option value="Avanta Garde">Avanta Garde</option>
                        
                        <option value="Bahnschrift">Bahnschrift</option>
                        <option value="Bahnschrift Light">Bahnschrift Light </option>
                        <option value="Bahnschrift SemiBold">Bahnschrift SemiBold</option>
                        <option value="Bahnschrift SemiLight">Bahnschrift SemiLight</option>
                        
                        <option value="Baskerville">Baskerville</option>
                        <option value="Batang">Batang </option>
                        <option value="BatangChe">BatangChe</option>
                        <option value="Big Caslon">Big Caslon</option>
                        
                        <option value="BIZ UDGothic">BIZ UDGothic</option>
                        <option value="BIZ UDMincho Medium">BIZ UDMincho Medium </option>
                        <option value="Blippo">Blippo</option>
                        <option value="Bodoni MT">Bodoni MT</option>
                        
                        <option value="Book Antiqua">Book Antiqua</option>
                        <option value="Bookman">Bookman </option>
                        <option value="Bradley Hand">Bradley Hand</option>
                        <option value="Browallia New">Browallia New</option>
                        
                        <option value="BrowalliaUPC">BrowalliaUPC</option>
                        <option value="Brush Script MT">Brush Script MT </option>
                        <option value="Brush Script Std">Brush Script Std</option>
                        <option value="Brushstroke">Brushstroke</option>
                        
                        <option value="Calibri">Calibri</option>
                        <option value="Calibri Light">Calibri Light </option>
                        <option value="Calisto MT">Calisto MT</option>
                        <option value="Cambodian">Cambodian</option>
                        
                        <option value="Cambria">Cambria</option>
                        <option value="Cambria Math">Cambria Math </option>
                        <option value="Candara">Candara</option>
                        <option value="Century Gothic">Century Gothic</option>
                        
                        <option value="Chalkduster">Chalkduster</option>
                        <option value="Cherokee">Cherokee </option>
                        <option value="Consolas">Consolas</option>
                        <option value="Constantia">Constantia</option>
                        
                        <option value="Copperplate">Copperplate</option>
                        <option value="Copperplate Gothic Light">Copperplate Gothic Light </option>
                        <option value="Copperplate Gothic Bold">Copperplate Gothic Bold</option>
                        <option value="Corbel">Corbel</option>
                        
                        <option value="Cordia New">Cordia New</option>
                        <option value="CordiaUPC">CordiaUPC </option>
                        <option value="Coronetscript">Coronetscript</option>
                        <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
                        
                        <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
                        <option value="DaunPenh">DaunPenh </option>
                        <option value="David">David</option>
                        <option value="DengXian">DengXian</option>
                        
                        <option value="DFKai-SB">DFKai-SB</option>
                        <option value="Didot">Didot </option>
                        <option value="DilleniaUPC">DilleniaUPC</option>
                        <option value="DokChampa">DokChampa</option>
                        
                        <option value="Dotum">Dotum</option>
                        <option value="DotumChe">DotumChe</option>
                        <option value="Ebrima">Ebrima</option>
                        <option value="Estrangelo Edessa">Estrangelo Edessa</option>
                        
                        <option value="EucrosiaUPC">EucrosiaUPC</option>
                        <option value="Euphemia">Euphemia</option>
                        <option value="FangSong">FangSong</option>
                        <option value="Franklin Gothic Medium">Franklin Gothic Medium</option>
                        
                        <option value="FrankRuehl">FrankRuehl</option>
                        <option value="FreesiaUPC">FreesiaUPC</option>
                        <option value="Futara">Futara</option>
                        <option value="Gabriola">Gabriola</option>
                        
                        <option value="Gadugi">Gadugi</option>
                        <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
                        <option value="Gautami">Gautami</option>
                        <option value="Geneva">Geneva</option>
                        
                        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="Georgia Pro">Georgia Pro </option>
                        <option value="Gill Sans">Gill Sans</option>
                        <option value="Gill Sans Nova">Gill Sans Nova</option>
                        
                        <option value="Gisha">Gisha</option>
                        <option value="Goudy Old Style">Goudy Old Style</option>
                        <option value="Gulim">Gulim</option>
                        <option value="GulimChe">GulimChe</option>
                        
                        <option value="Gungsuh">Gungsuh</option>
                        <option value="GungsuhChe">GungsuhChe</option>
                        <option value="Hebrew">Hebrew</option>
                        <option value="Hoefler Text">Hoefler Text</option>
                        
                        <option value="HoloLens MDL2 Assets">HoloLens MDL2 Assets</option>
                        <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
                        <option value="Ink Free">Ink Free</option>
                        <option value="IrisUPC">IrisUPC</option>
                        
                        <option value="Iskoola Pota">Iskoola Pota</option>
                        <option value="Japanese">Japanese</option>
                        <option value="Jazz LET">Jazz LET</option>
                        <option value="KaiTi">KaiTi</option>
                        
                        <option value="Kalinga">Kalinga</option>
                        <option value="Kartika">Kartika</option>
                        <option value="Khmer UI">Khmer UI</option>
                        <option value="KodchiangUPC">KodchiangUPC</option>
                        
                        <option value="Kokila">Kokila</option>
                        <option value="Korean">Korean </option>
                        <option value="Lao">Lao</option>
                        <option value="Lao UI">Lao UI</option>
                        
                        <option value="Latha">Latha</option>
                        <option value="Leelawadee">Leelawadee</option>
                        <option value="Leelawadee UI">Leelawadee UI</option>
                        <option value="Leelawadee UI Semilight">Leelawadee UI Semilight</option>
                        
                        <option value="Levenim MT">Levenim MT</option>
                        <option value="LilyUPC">LilyUPC </option>
                        <option value="Lucida Bright">Lucida Bright</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Console">Lucida Console</option>
                        
                        <option value="Lucida Handwriting">Lucida Handwriting</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Sans">Lucida Sans </option>
                        <option value="Lucida Sans Typewriter">Lucida Sans Typewriter</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Sans Unicode">Lucida Sans Unicode</option>
                        
                        <option value="Lucidatypewriter">Lucidatypewriter</option>
                        <option value="Luminari">Luminari </option>
                        <option value="Malgun Gothic">Malgun Gothic</option>
                        <option value="Malgun Gothic Semilight">Malgun Gothic Semilight</option>
                        
                        <option value="Mangal">Mangal</option>
                        <option value="Marker Felt">Marker Felt</option>
                        <option value="Marlett">Marlett</option>
                        <option value="Meiryo">Meiryo</option>
                        
                        <option value="Meiryo UI">Meiryo UI</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft Himalaya">Microsoft Himalaya</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft JhengHei">Microsoft JhengHei</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft JhengHei UI">Microsoft JhengHei UI</option>
                        
                        <option value="Microsoft New Tai Lue">Microsoft New Tai Lue</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft PhagsPa">Microsoft PhagsPa</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft Sans Serif">Microsoft Sans Serif</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft Tai Le">Microsoft Tai Le</option>
                        
                        <option value="Microsoft Uighur">Microsoft Uighur</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft YaHei">Microsoft YaHei</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft Yi Baiti">Microsoft Yi Baiti</option>
                        <option value="MingLiU">MingLiU</option>
                        
                        <option value="MingLiU_HKSCS">MingLiU_HKSCS</option>
                        <option value="MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB">MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB</option>
                        <option value="MingLiU-ExtB">MingLiU-ExtB</option>
                        <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                        
                        <option value="Mongolian Baiti">Mongolian Baiti</option>
                        <option value="MoolBoran">MoolBoran </option>
                        <option value="MS Gothic">MS Gothic</option>
                        <option value="MS Mincho">MS Mincho</option>
                        
                        <option value="MS PGothic">MS PGothic</option>
                        <option value="MS PMincho">MS PMincho</option>
                        <option value="MS UI Gothic">MS UI Gothic</option>
                        <option value="Myanmar Text">Myanmar Text</option>
                        
                        <option value="Narkisim">Narkisim</option>
                        <option value="Neue Haas Grotesk Text Pro">Neue Haas Grotesk Text Pro</option>
                        <option value="New Century Schoolbook">New Century Schoolbook</option>
                        <option value="News Gothic MT">News Gothic MT</option>
                        
                        <option value="No automatic language associations">No automatic language associations</option>
                        <option value="papyrus">Noto</option>
                        <option value="NSimSun">NSimSun</option>
                        <option value="Oldtown">Oldtown</option>
                        
                        <option value="Optima">Optima</option>
                        <option value="Palatino">Palatino </option>
                        <option value="Palatino Linotype">Palatino Linotype</option>
                        <option value="papyrus">papyrus</option>
                        
                        <option value="Parkavenue">Parkavenue</option>
                        <option value="Perpetua">Perpetua</option>
                        <option value="Plantagenet Cherokee">Plantagenet Cherokee</option>
                        <option value="PMingLiU">PMingLiU</option>
                        
                        <option value="Raavi">Raavi</option>
                        <option value="Rockwell">Rockwell</option>
                        <option value="Rockwell Extra Bold">Rockwell Extra Bold</option>
                        <option value="Rockwell Nova">Rockwell Nova</option>
                        
                        <option value="Rockwell Nova Cond">Rockwell Nova Cond</option>
                        <option value="Rockwell Nova Extra Bold">Rockwell Nova Extra Bold</option>
                        <option value="Rod">Rod</option>
                        <option value="Sakkal Majalla">Sakkal Majalla</option>
                        
                        <option value="Sanskrit Text">Sanskrit Text</option>
                        <option value="Segoe MDL2 Assets">Segoe MDL2 Assets</option>
                        <option value="Segoe Print">Segoe Print</option>
                        <option value="Segoe Script">Segoe Script</option>
                        
                        <option value="Segoe UI">Segoe UI</option>
                        <option value="Segoe UI Emoji">Segoe UI Emoji</option>
                        <option value="Segoe UI Historic">Segoe UI Historic</option>
                        <option value="Segoe UI Symbol">Segoe UI Symbol</option>
                        
                        <option value="Shonar Bangla">Shonar Bangla</option>
                        <option value="SimHei">SimHei</option>
                        <option value="SimKai">SimKai</option>
                        <option value="Simplified Arabic">Simplified Arabic</option>
                        
                        <option value="Simplified Chinese">Simplified Chinese</option>
                        <option value="SimSun">SimSun</option>
                        <option value="SimSun-ExtB">SimSun-ExtB</option>
                        <option value="Sitka">Sitka</option>
                        
                        <option value="Stencil Std">Stencil Std</option>
                        <option value="Sylfaen">Sylfaen</option>
                        <option value="Symbol">Symbol</option>
                        <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
                        
                        <option value="Thai">Thai</option>
                        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman </option>
                        <option value="Traditional Arabic">Traditional Arabic</option>
                        <option value="Traditional Chinese">Traditional Chinese</option>
                        
                        <option value="Trattatello">Trattatello</option>
                        <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
                        <option value="Tunga">Tunga</option>
                        <option value="UD Digi KyoKasho NP-R">UD Digi KyoKasho NP-R</option>
                        
                        <option value="UD Digi KyoKasho NK-R">UD Digi KyoKasho NK-R</option>
                        <option value="UD Digi KyoKasho N-R">UD Digi KyoKasho N-R</option>
                        <option value="Urdu Typesetting">Urdu Typesetting</option>
                        <option value="Vani">Vani</option>
                        
                        <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
                        <option value="Verdana Pro">Verdana Pro</option>
                        <option value="Vijaya">Vijaya</option>
                        <option value="Vrinda">Vrinda</option>
                        
                        <option value="Webdings">Webdings</option>
                        <option value="Westminster">Westminster</option>
                        <option value="Wingdings">Wingdings</option>
                        <option value="Yu Gothic">Yu Gothic</option>
                        
                        <option value="Yu Gothic UI">Yu Gothic UI</option>
                        <option value="Yu Mincho">Yu Mincho</option>
                        <option value="Zapf Chancery">Zapf Chancery</option>
                        
                    </select>
```

Comment: like this... `$('#yourDivID').css("font-family", $('select#font_families option:selected').val());` or use [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

**I hope to solve your problem**

```js
$('#font_families').on('change',function(){
 $('#test_text').css("font-family", $(this).val());
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_text">Test Text</div>

<select id="font_families">
                        <option value="Select" selected disabled>Select</option>
                        <option value="JasmineUPC">JasmineUPC</option>
                        <option value="Javanese Text">Javanese Text</option>
                        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                        <option value="Verdana">Verdana </option>
                        <option value="Impact">Impact </option>
                        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
                        
                        <option value="Geneva">Geneva</option>
                        <option value="Segoe UI">Segoe UI</option>
                        <option value="Optima">Optima</option>
                        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                        
                        <option value="Big Caslon">Big Caslon</option>
                        <option value="Bodoni MT">Bodoni MT</option>
                        <option value="Book Antiqua">Book Antiqua</option>
                        <option value="Bookman">Bookman</option>
                        
                        <option value="New Century Schoolbook">New Century Schoolbook</option>
                        <option value="Calisto MT">Calisto MT </option>
                        <option value="Cambria">Cambria</option>
                        <option value="Didot">Didot</option>
                        
                        <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
                        <option value="Georgia">Georgia </option>
                        <option value="Goudy Old Style">Goudy Old Style</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Bright">Lucida Bright</option>
                        
                        <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
                        <option value="Perpetua ">Perpetua </option>
                        <option value="Rockwell">Rockwell</option>
                        <option value="Rockwell Extra Bold">Rockwell Extra Bold</option>
                        
                        <option value="Consolas">Consolas</option>
                        <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
                        <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Console">Lucida Console</option>
                        
                        <option value="Lucidatypewriter">Lucidatypewriter</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Sans Typewriter">Lucida Sans Typewriter</option>
                        <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                        <option value="Andale Mono">Andale Mono</option>
                        
                        <option value="Apple Chancery">Apple Chancery</option>
                        <option value="Zapf Chancery">Zapf Chancery</option>
                        <option value="Bradley Hand">Bradley Hand</option>
                        <option value="Brush Script MT">Brush Script MT</option>
                        
                        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                        <option value="Verdana ">Verdana </option>
                        <option value="Impact ">Impact </option>
                        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
                        
                        <option value="Brush Script Std">Brush Script Std</option>
                        <option value="Snell Roundhan">Snell Roundhan</option>
                        <option value="URW Chancery">URW Chancery</option>
                        <option value="Coronet script">Coronet script</option>
                        
                        <option value="Florence">Florence</option>
                        <option value="Parkavenue">Parkavenue </option>
                        <option value="Brushstroke">Brushstroke</option>
                        <option value="Luminari">Luminari</option>
                        
                        <option value="Chalkduster">Chalkduster</option>
                        <option value="Jazz LET">Jazz LET </option>
                        <option value="Blippo">Blippo</option>
                        <option value="Stencil Std">Stencil Std</option>
                        
                        <option value="Marker Felt">Marker Felt</option>
                        <option value="Trattatello">Trattatello </option>
                        <option value="Arnoldboecklin">Arnoldboecklin</option>
                        <option value="Oldtown">Oldtown</option>
                        
                        <option value="Copperplate">Copperplate</option>
                        <option value="papyrus">papyrus </option>
                        <option value="Abadi MT Condensed Light">Abadi MT Condensed Light</option>
                        <option value="Aharoni">Aharoni</option>
                        
                        <option value="Aharoni Bold">Aharoni Bold</option>
                        <option value="Aldhabi">Aldhabi </option>
                        <option value="AlternateGothic2 BT">AlternateGothic2 BT</option>
                        <option value="Andale Mono">Andale Mono</option>
                        
                        <option value="Andalus">Andalus</option>
                        <option value="Angsana New">Angsana New </option>
                        <option value="AngsanaUPC">AngsanaUPC</option>
                        <option value="Aparajita">Aparajita</option>
                        
                        <option value="Apple Chancery">Apple Chancery</option>
                        <option value="Arabic Typesetting">Arabic Typesetting </option>
                        <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
                        <option value="Arial narrow">Arial narrow</option>
                        
                        <option value="Arial Nova">Arial Nova</option>
                        <option value="Arial Rounded MT Bold">Arial Rounded MT Bold </option>
                        <option value="Arnoldboecklin">Arnoldboecklin</option>
                        <option value="Avanta Garde">Avanta Garde</option>
                        
                        <option value="Bahnschrift">Bahnschrift</option>
                        <option value="Bahnschrift Light">Bahnschrift Light </option>
                        <option value="Bahnschrift SemiBold">Bahnschrift SemiBold</option>
                        <option value="Bahnschrift SemiLight">Bahnschrift SemiLight</option>
                        
                        <option value="Baskerville">Baskerville</option>
                        <option value="Batang">Batang </option>
                        <option value="BatangChe">BatangChe</option>
                        <option value="Big Caslon">Big Caslon</option>
                        
                        <option value="BIZ UDGothic">BIZ UDGothic</option>
                        <option value="BIZ UDMincho Medium">BIZ UDMincho Medium </option>
                        <option value="Blippo">Blippo</option>
                        <option value="Bodoni MT">Bodoni MT</option>
                        
                        <option value="Book Antiqua">Book Antiqua</option>
                        <option value="Bookman">Bookman </option>
                        <option value="Bradley Hand">Bradley Hand</option>
                        <option value="Browallia New">Browallia New</option>
                        
                        <option value="BrowalliaUPC">BrowalliaUPC</option>
                        <option value="Brush Script MT">Brush Script MT </option>
                        <option value="Brush Script Std">Brush Script Std</option>
                        <option value="Brushstroke">Brushstroke</option>
                        
                        <option value="Calibri">Calibri</option>
                        <option value="Calibri Light">Calibri Light </option>
                        <option value="Calisto MT">Calisto MT</option>
                        <option value="Cambodian">Cambodian</option>
                        
                        <option value="Cambria">Cambria</option>
                        <option value="Cambria Math">Cambria Math </option>
                        <option value="Candara">Candara</option>
                        <option value="Century Gothic">Century Gothic</option>
                        
                        <option value="Chalkduster">Chalkduster</option>
                        <option value="Cherokee">Cherokee </option>
                        <option value="Consolas">Consolas</option>
                        <option value="Constantia">Constantia</option>
                        
                        <option value="Copperplate">Copperplate</option>
                        <option value="Copperplate Gothic Light">Copperplate Gothic Light </option>
                        <option value="Copperplate Gothic Bold">Copperplate Gothic Bold</option>
                        <option value="Corbel">Corbel</option>
                        
                        <option value="Cordia New">Cordia New</option>
                        <option value="CordiaUPC">CordiaUPC </option>
                        <option value="Coronetscript">Coronetscript</option>
                        <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
                        
                        <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
                        <option value="DaunPenh">DaunPenh </option>
                        <option value="David">David</option>
                        <option value="DengXian">DengXian</option>
                        
                        <option value="DFKai-SB">DFKai-SB</option>
                        <option value="Didot">Didot </option>
                        <option value="DilleniaUPC">DilleniaUPC</option>
                        <option value="DokChampa">DokChampa</option>
                        
                        <option value="Dotum">Dotum</option>
                        <option value="DotumChe">DotumChe</option>
                        <option value="Ebrima">Ebrima</option>
                        <option value="Estrangelo Edessa">Estrangelo Edessa</option>
                        
                        <option value="EucrosiaUPC">EucrosiaUPC</option>
                        <option value="Euphemia">Euphemia</option>
                        <option value="FangSong">FangSong</option>
                        <option value="Franklin Gothic Medium">Franklin Gothic Medium</option>
                        
                        <option value="FrankRuehl">FrankRuehl</option>
                        <option value="FreesiaUPC">FreesiaUPC</option>
                        <option value="Futara">Futara</option>
                        <option value="Gabriola">Gabriola</option>
                        
                        <option value="Gadugi">Gadugi</option>
                        <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
                        <option value="Gautami">Gautami</option>
                        <option value="Geneva">Geneva</option>
                        
                        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="Georgia Pro">Georgia Pro </option>
                        <option value="Gill Sans">Gill Sans</option>
                        <option value="Gill Sans Nova">Gill Sans Nova</option>
                        
                        <option value="Gisha">Gisha</option>
                        <option value="Goudy Old Style">Goudy Old Style</option>
                        <option value="Gulim">Gulim</option>
                        <option value="GulimChe">GulimChe</option>
                        
                        <option value="Gungsuh">Gungsuh</option>
                        <option value="GungsuhChe">GungsuhChe</option>
                        <option value="Hebrew">Hebrew</option>
                        <option value="Hoefler Text">Hoefler Text</option>
                        
                        <option value="HoloLens MDL2 Assets">HoloLens MDL2 Assets</option>
                        <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
                        <option value="Ink Free">Ink Free</option>
                        <option value="IrisUPC">IrisUPC</option>
                        
                        <option value="Iskoola Pota">Iskoola Pota</option>
                        <option value="Japanese">Japanese</option>
                        <option value="Jazz LET">Jazz LET</option>
                        <option value="KaiTi">KaiTi</option>
                        
                        <option value="Kalinga">Kalinga</option>
                        <option value="Kartika">Kartika</option>
                        <option value="Khmer UI">Khmer UI</option>
                        <option value="KodchiangUPC">KodchiangUPC</option>
                        
                        <option value="Kokila">Kokila</option>
                        <option value="Korean">Korean </option>
                        <option value="Lao">Lao</option>
                        <option value="Lao UI">Lao UI</option>
                        
                        <option value="Latha">Latha</option>
                        <option value="Leelawadee">Leelawadee</option>
                        <option value="Leelawadee UI">Leelawadee UI</option>
                        <option value="Leelawadee UI Semilight">Leelawadee UI Semilight</option>
                        
                        <option value="Levenim MT">Levenim MT</option>
                        <option value="LilyUPC">LilyUPC </option>
                        <option value="Lucida Bright">Lucida Bright</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Console">Lucida Console</option>
                        
                        <option value="Lucida Handwriting">Lucida Handwriting</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Sans">Lucida Sans </option>
                        <option value="Lucida Sans Typewriter">Lucida Sans Typewriter</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Sans Unicode">Lucida Sans Unicode</option>
                        
                        <option value="Lucidatypewriter">Lucidatypewriter</option>
                        <option value="Luminari">Luminari </option>
                        <option value="Malgun Gothic">Malgun Gothic</option>
                        <option value="Malgun Gothic Semilight">Malgun Gothic Semilight</option>
                        
                        <option value="Mangal">Mangal</option>
                        <option value="Marker Felt">Marker Felt</option>
                        <option value="Marlett">Marlett</option>
                        <option value="Meiryo">Meiryo</option>
                        
                        <option value="Meiryo UI">Meiryo UI</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft Himalaya">Microsoft Himalaya</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft JhengHei">Microsoft JhengHei</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft JhengHei UI">Microsoft JhengHei UI</option>
                        
                        <option value="Microsoft New Tai Lue">Microsoft New Tai Lue</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft PhagsPa">Microsoft PhagsPa</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft Sans Serif">Microsoft Sans Serif</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft Tai Le">Microsoft Tai Le</option>
                        
                        <option value="Microsoft Uighur">Microsoft Uighur</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft YaHei">Microsoft YaHei</option>
                        <option value="Microsoft Yi Baiti">Microsoft Yi Baiti</option>
                        <option value="MingLiU">MingLiU</option>
                        
                        <option value="MingLiU_HKSCS">MingLiU_HKSCS</option>
                        <option value="MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB">MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB</option>
                        <option value="MingLiU-ExtB">MingLiU-ExtB</option>
                        <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                        
                        <option value="Mongolian Baiti">Mongolian Baiti</option>
                        <option value="MoolBoran">MoolBoran </option>
                        <option value="MS Gothic">MS Gothic</option>
                        <option value="MS Mincho">MS Mincho</option>
                        
                        <option value="MS PGothic">MS PGothic</option>
                        <option value="MS PMincho">MS PMincho</option>
                        <option value="MS UI Gothic">MS UI Gothic</option>
                        <option value="Myanmar Text">Myanmar Text</option>
                        
                        <option value="Narkisim">Narkisim</option>
                        <option value="Neue Haas Grotesk Text Pro">Neue Haas Grotesk Text Pro</option>
                        <option value="New Century Schoolbook">New Century Schoolbook</option>
                        <option value="News Gothic MT">News Gothic MT</option>
                        
                        <option value="No automatic language associations">No automatic language associations</option>
                        <option value="papyrus">Noto</option>
                        <option value="NSimSun">NSimSun</option>
                        <option value="Oldtown">Oldtown</option>
                        
                        <option value="Optima">Optima</option>
                        <option value="Palatino">Palatino </option>
                        <option value="Palatino Linotype">Palatino Linotype</option>
                        <option value="papyrus">papyrus</option>
                        
                        <option value="Parkavenue">Parkavenue</option>
                        <option value="Perpetua">Perpetua</option>
                        <option value="Plantagenet Cherokee">Plantagenet Cherokee</option>
                        <option value="PMingLiU">PMingLiU</option>
                        
                        <option value="Raavi">Raavi</option>
                        <option value="Rockwell">Rockwell</option>
                        <option value="Rockwell Extra Bold">Rockwell Extra Bold</option>
                        <option value="Rockwell Nova">Rockwell Nova</option>
                        
                        <option value="Rockwell Nova Cond">Rockwell Nova Cond</option>
                        <option value="Rockwell Nova Extra Bold">Rockwell Nova Extra Bold</option>
                        <option value="Rod">Rod</option>
                        <option value="Sakkal Majalla">Sakkal Majalla</option>
                        
                        <option value="Sanskrit Text">Sanskrit Text</option>
                        <option value="Segoe MDL2 Assets">Segoe MDL2 Assets</option>
                        <option value="Segoe Print">Segoe Print</option>
                        <option value="Segoe Script">Segoe Script</option>
                        
                        <option value="Segoe UI">Segoe UI</option>
                        <option value="Segoe UI Emoji">Segoe UI Emoji</option>
                        <option value="Segoe UI Historic">Segoe UI Historic</option>
                        <option value="Segoe UI Symbol">Segoe UI Symbol</option>
                        
                        <option value="Shonar Bangla">Shonar Bangla</option>
                        <option value="SimHei">SimHei</option>
                        <option value="SimKai">SimKai</option>
                        <option value="Simplified Arabic">Simplified Arabic</option>
                        
                        <option value="Simplified Chinese">Simplified Chinese</option>
                        <option value="SimSun">SimSun</option>
                        <option value="SimSun-ExtB">SimSun-ExtB</option>
                        <option value="Sitka">Sitka</option>
                        
                        <option value="Stencil Std">Stencil Std</option>
                        <option value="Sylfaen">Sylfaen</option>
                        <option value="Symbol">Symbol</option>
                        <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
                        
                        <option value="Thai">Thai</option>
                        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman </option>
                        <option value="Traditional Arabic">Traditional Arabic</option>
                        <option value="Traditional Chinese">Traditional Chinese</option>
                        
                        <option value="Trattatello">Trattatello</option>
                        <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
                        <option value="Tunga">Tunga</option>
                        <option value="UD Digi KyoKasho NP-R">UD Digi KyoKasho NP-R</option>
                        
                        <option value="UD Digi KyoKasho NK-R">UD Digi KyoKasho NK-R</option>
                        <option value="UD Digi KyoKasho N-R">UD Digi KyoKasho N-R</option>
                        <option value="Urdu Typesetting">Urdu Typesetting</option>
                        <option value="Vani">Vani</option>
                        
                        <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
                        <option value="Verdana Pro">Verdana Pro</option>
                        <option value="Vijaya">Vijaya</option>
                        <option value="Vrinda">Vrinda</option>
                        
                        <option value="Webdings">Webdings</option>
                        <option value="Westminster">Westminster</option>
                        <option value="Wingdings">Wingdings</option>
                        <option value="Yu Gothic">Yu Gothic</option>
                        
                        <option value="Yu Gothic UI">Yu Gothic UI</option>
                        <option value="Yu Mincho">Yu Mincho</option>
                        <option value="Zapf Chancery">Zapf Chancery</option>
                        
                    </select>
```